# Fancybox 3 and Bootstrap 3 Modal oddly bug

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, fancybox-3

I have decided to try [fancybox 3](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) recently and found a very strange bug which appears only with open bootstrap modal window.

So I've made a little demo as an example (see in full page mode)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/fancyapps/fancybox/master/dist/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/fancyapps/fancybox/master/dist/jquery.fancybox.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

<!-- Gallery modal -->
<div id="galleryModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="galleryModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Cats Gallery</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <a href="http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/featurebox_sidebar_kids/grief-and-loss.jpg"
           data-fancybox="gallery"
           class="btn btn-default"
           >Show Cat 1</a>
        <a href="http://cdn1-www.cattime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/persian-cats-and-kittens/persian-cats-and-kittens-1.jpg"
           data-fancybox="gallery"
           class="btn btn-default"
           >Show Cat 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#galleryModal">Show cats</button>
<br />
<br />
<a href="http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/featurebox_sidebar_kids/grief-and-loss.jpg"
   data-fancybox="gallery2"
   class="btn btn-default"
   >Show Cat 1</a>
<a href="http://cdn1-www.cattime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/persian-cats-and-kittens/persian-cats-and-kittens-1.jpg"
   data-fancybox="gallery2"
   class="btn btn-default"
   >Show Cat 2</a>
```

When you are just opening the picture and selecting previous or next, all is fine. But when you're doing the same thing from bootstrap modal window ... see the browser console ... it's full of  mistakes. Looks like focus event by fancybox oddly intersects with modal's focus event.

And my question is how can I fix this without changing libraries code?

Comment: I had added an [issue](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/issues/1288) to fancy box. You can check its status there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using fancyBox v3, you do not need any additional script for modal functionality. You could simply use fancyBox to display both modals.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/fancyapps/fancybox/master/dist/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/fancyapps/fancybox/master/dist/jquery.fancybox.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

<!-- Gallery modal -->


    <div id="galleryModal" class="modal-content" style="display:none;">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-fancybox-close aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Cats Gallery</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <a href="http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/featurebox_sidebar_kids/grief-and-loss.jpg"
           data-fancybox="gallery"
           class="btn btn-default"
           >Show Cat 1</a>
        <a href="http://cdn1-www.cattime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/persian-cats-and-kittens/persian-cats-and-kittens-1.jpg"
           data-fancybox="gallery"
           class="btn btn-default"
           >Show Cat 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>



<button class="btn btn-default" data-fancybox data-options='{"smallBtn":false, "buttons":false}' data-src="#galleryModal">Show cats</button>
<br />
<br />
<a href="http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/featurebox_sidebar_kids/grief-and-loss.jpg"
   data-fancybox="gallery2"
   class="btn btn-default"
   >Show Cat 1</a>
<a href="http://cdn1-www.cattime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/persian-cats-and-kittens/persian-cats-and-kittens-1.jpg"
   data-fancybox="gallery2"
   class="btn btn-default"
   >Show Cat 2</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for advice. But as a developer I prefer getting to know the root of issue. Or, for example, the customer insists only on bootstrap modals :)

Comment: It is simple. Both fancyBox and Bootstrap try to trap focus. Therefore it starts looping - close button gets focus inside fancyBox -> Bootstrap modal tries to get focus -> fancyBox tries to set focus back -> Bootstrap modal tried to get it back -> ....